# Plot graphs using Python matplotlib with aligned y-axis

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, matplotlib, graph

I am attempting to plot a graph similar to the one attached below. The y-axis should be aligned and the x-axis scale and name should be same. Also, I want the dotted line as shown in the figure.

I tried combining two different graphs but that is certainly not a good way to solve this.

[image]

Sorry for the poor quality picture but the important points are mentioned.

Answer (score -1):

Look into the matplotlib [docs](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/shared_axis_demo.html). I think you might be looking to use `plt.subplots` with the `sharex` argument.